# Applescript: using both "on open" and "choose file"

Tags: applescript

Is there a way to use both "on open" and "choose file" in my script without having to repeat the action code as in my example below?

```
on open myMovie
    tell application "Quicktime Player 7"
    open myMovie
    end tell
end open

set myMovie to choose file
    tell application "Quicktime Player 7"
    open myMovie
    end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

```
on open myMovies
    repeat with aMovie in myMovies
        tell application "QuickTime Player 7" to open aMovie
    end repeat
end open

on run
    set myMovie to choose file
    tell application "QuickTime Player 7" to open myMovie
end run
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply adayzdone, but some users of the Applet want to be able to open it and choose a file, instead of dragging a file onto it. So I need both behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to call the script's open handler from the run handler:

```
on open theFiles
    tell application "QuickTime Player 7" to open theFiles
end open

tell me to open (choose file)
```